# CSS file is not being picked up

Tags: html, css, jsp

I've created css files that I would like to use. However, I can't seem to get my html and jsp files to pick them up. My project hierarchy is as follows:

```
my_project
    `-- src
        `-- main
            |-- resources
            |   `-- META-INF
            |       `-- resources
            |           |-- index2.css
            |           `-- index.html
            `-- webapp
                `-- WEB-INF
                    |-- css
                    |   `-- index.css
                    `-- jsp
                        `-- DataViews
                            `-- Data.jsp
```

My index.html can be reduced to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WEB-INF/css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/index2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index2.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index2.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My index2.css:

```
img {
  width: 533;
  height: 230;
}
```

My Data.jsp can be reduced to the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="WEB-INF/css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/index.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Available Containers:</th>
            <th>File Count</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${model.containers}" var="container">
            <tr>
                <td>${container.getCount()}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

My index.css:

```
img {
  max-width: 533px;
  max-height: 230px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

th {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

tr:hover {background-color: #f5f5f5;}
```

As you can see, I've tried a bunch of ways of reaching my css files with no luck. Nothing seems to change on the UI. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are using some kind of framework to create this, I suggest using their guide for resource link, there must be some method to link resources from plublic url, it is Spring MVC? see this url https://mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/ if so

Comment: @Mohsin you were correct. I was using Spring boot, and it seems their framework specifies certain locations for css files such as src/main/resources/static/.